If a parent writes to their child “Always on our mind”, meaning the child is on both the mom and dad’s mind, should “mind” be singular or plural
I am still confused regarding the use of “mind” or “minds”. Say as a mom you write a text to your daughter and you end your text with “always on our mind”. Meaning, the daughter is always on her mom AND her dad’s mind. Should the mom in this case write “always on our MINDS” or “always on our MIND”?

Compare this, this, this, this, this.

Does this answer your question? "Everybody's using a cell phone nowadays" vs. "Everybody's using cell phones nowadays" In this case, the distributive singular (mind) is fine (cf 'get something off their chest'), as is the distributive plural. Both are used.

Maybe they're all thinking about you individually, or maybe when they're together they're talking about you. The former is individual and suggests "minds"; the latter collective, so "mind". It's a case where either is fine, though you may want to consider implications.
